# i need to update quantity separately, but when i update it updates all of the quantities

Tags: php, html, mysqli, sql-update, cart

```
<tr align="center">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remove[]" value="<?php echo $pro_id;?>">//removes checked items  
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="admin_area/product_images/<?php echo $product_image?>" width="60" height="60"/><br>//displays products image
      <?php echo $product_title ?>//displays products title
  </td>
  <td>
      <input type="text" size="4" name="qty" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["qty"]; ?>"><span style="color:red">Required</span>
  </td>//textbox where user enters the new quantity
  <input type="hidden" name="pro_id" value="<?php echo $pro_id; ?>">
</td>
<?php
$sql = "select * from cart";
$run_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)) {
    $_SESSION["qty"] = $row['qty'];
}

if (isset($_POST['update_cart'])) {
    $ip = getIp();
    $Updateqty = $_POST['qty'];
    //get quantity from the text boxes which are repeated with every product

    $pro_id = $_POST['pro_id'];
    //gets the id from the hidden field

    $update_qty = "UPDATE cart SET qty='$Updateqty' where p_id='$pro_id' and ip_add='$ip'";
    $run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $update_qty);

    if ($run_qty) {
        echo"<script>window.open('cart.php','_self')</script>";
    }
}
?>
</tr>
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code. Are you sure `$pro_id` and `$ip` are set properly?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: You have to have `session_start();` at the top of all pages using sessions, is it in place?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard yes the ip is a function i made for getting user ip addresses, and i have a session started as well

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem here:

```
$sql = "select * from cart";
$run_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)) {
    $_SESSION["qty"] = $row['qty'];
}
```

This while loop will overwrite `$_SESSION["qty"]` with each iteration, so it will always be set to the quantity of the last item in the cart.

Then that session value is used in the display for each item.

```
<input type="text" size="4" name="qty" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["qty"]; ?>"><span style="color:red">Required</span>
```

Also, if what you've shown in your question is one row from a table that has multiple rows, and you have wrapped the entire table in one form, every input will be submitted, and since you have multiple values for `qty` and `pro_id`, only the last one will be used. This is what is making it look like every quantity is being updated.

---

I would suggest an approach like this to get it working. This may not work for you as-is, because I guessed on some of the names, but should be enough to show what I have in mind:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['update_cart'])) {
    $ip = getIp();

    // prepare an update statement
    $sql = "UPDATE cart SET qty=? where p_id=? and ip_add=?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);

    // loop over each quantity and update
    foreach ($_POST['qty'] as $pro_id => $qty) {
        $stmt->bind_param("iis", $qty, $pro_id, $ip);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}

$sql = "select * from cart";
$run_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)) {
    // update the session with the new values
    $_SESSION[$row['p_id']]['qty'] = $row['qty'];
}

?>
```

That should update quantity for each item, but it depends on an array of `qty` values being provided by your form. In order to have that, you need to name your inputs using an array syntax like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>Other product info</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" 
                    name="qty[<?php echo $product['id'] ?>]"
                    value="<?php echo $_SESSION[$product['id']]['qty']; ?>">
            </td>
        </tr>            
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="update_cart" value="Update Cart">
</form>
```

Comment: The UPDATE query isn't in the while loop and the OP is using a different variable in the UPDATE: `$Updateqty=$_POST['qty'];` But *yikes* I do see where the logic is screwed up.

Comment: @JayBlanchard There's no form in the question code, which implies that there's one form wrapping multiple instances of the tr that they've shown. So I think it looks like they have a lot of different instances of `qty` and `pro_id`, and they'll always get the last one.

Comment: Oh, and I just noticed that the closing tr is after the PHP code, so it might be repeated as well.

Comment: Yeah, it looks a mess from here for sure.

Comment: You re correct the last row in the table is the only one updating, how can i escape that, i need to update a specific value for each row, also the whole thing is wrapped in one form

Comment: @ImadFarran I updated the answer with my suggestion for how to handle this.

Comment: @Don'tPanic the update worked for each item, thanks ! but i still have a problem with displaying it from the database, first item always says "br /><b>Notice</b>: Undefined offset: 7 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\ecommerce\cart.php</b> on line <b>108</b><br />", i used this to save the row in session: $_SESSION[$row['p_id']]['qty'] = $row['qty']; and to echo: echo $_SESSION[$pro_id]['qty'] //its on line 108